# Persistence of constants between invocations in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an issue in rails console that is puzzling. I am using rails 4.2.5.2 on El Capitain.

I have some constants stored in a file called `config/initializers/constants.rb`:

```
POPULATIONS = Regions.read_populations_from_file
TEST_CONSTANT = "A"
```

If I run rails c I see the populations values correctly.
If I terminate `rails c`, edit the regions data file, and run `rails c` again the `POPULATIONS` constant shows the old values.
If I then terminate rails c, change `TEST_CONSTANT` to "B", and run rails c again I get the correct `POPULATIONS` again.

The bad caching of the `POPULATIONS` constant survives closing all shell windows on the system (and also running `Terminal :: Quit Terminal` after that).

Does anyone know why this is? Why are `POPULATIONS` stale (even surviving terminations of `rails c`)? Why does changing `TEST_CONSTANT` fix it? Thanks for any info.

Comment: Removing the Spring gem makes the behavior go away. Spring must keep running outside terminal shells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of `spring` - it launches rails in background. Upon changing the file it does not reload, because it does not know about your data file, but it reloads upon changing the source file.

To fix - run `bin/spring stop` each time you want a complete reload

Comment: yeah, stupid spring. Brings me more troubles than benefits :)